# Compare two dataframes and return result of a row in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to compare Input DataFrame with Main DataFrame and return the value of matching row to the input data,

Consider the example below

**Input DataFrame**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

**Main DataFrame**

| A | B | C | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | P1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | P2 |

After comparing the Input with main DataFrame the result should be like below

**Output DataFrame**

| A | B | C | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | P2 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | P1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result_df = input_df.join(main_df, ["A", "B", "C"], "left") \
    .withColumn("Point", F.coalesce(F.col("Point"), F.lit("NA")))

result_df.show()

#+---+---+---+-----+
#|  A|  B|  C|Point|
#+---+---+---+-----+
#|  0|  0|  0|   NA|
#|  1|  0|  1|   P2|
#|  1|  1|  1|   P1|
#|  0|  1|  1|   NA|
#+---+---+---+-----+
```